# Is there a way to prevent Tomcat from crashing when a loaded JNI library corrupts memory?

Tags: java, tomcat, crash, java-native-interface

We have a web application running on Tomcat 7 and it loads a JNI library module that was coded in C++ and which was developped by a third party. Basically, this library provides biometric technology to our web app. We cannot use an all java solution for this and have no other choice than to use that JNI library module.

The problem is that sometimes, the JNI library module crashes because it does a segmentation fault and corrupts memory. When that happens, it makes Tomcat crash completely without warning.

Is there a way to prevent tomcat from completely crashing when a loaded JNI library module crashes? Ideally, when the JNI library module crashes, we would like to be notified and have a chance to reload the web app/module. Is that possible?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start another JVM which loads the JNI library.  When the JVM dies, you can restart start it from your Tomcat.

Comment: PRobably you want to complete your answer with: you have to establish some sort of communication between the JVMs also. Anyway, i like your idea

Comment: Quite likely, however std in/out might be enough and that is given to you by Process.

Comment: Right now we use a second JVM to monitor Tomcat. When Tomcat crashes, the monitoring app restarts it automatically. This is not ideal but required no code change in the original web app. I realize that inter-JVM communication is far more elegant but also more involved.

Comment: @John, The other solution is to get the C++ library fixed, but I guess you thought of that already.  Perhaps whomever supports the library can suggest an alternative to fixing it. ;)

Comment: @Peter, Yes I agree with you, they should fix it. :) I told them about it but we have a hard time reproducing the error and they have no clue on why it happens.

Comment: @John, The problem could even be in the JNI layer you use to call the C++. :(

Comment: @Peter, No, from the stack traces we see that culprit is inside the library itself. :( The JNI layer does everything possible to catch exceptions, but it seems there is nothing we can do against memory corruption occurring upstream.