# Why does NetBeans declare low memory when I run an LWJGL-based Java app several times?

Tags: java, opengl, netbeans, java-native-interface, lwjgl

Currently experimenting with OpenGL in Java. After running the following test code several cycles within NetBeans, I receive a low memory error and the program terminates.  The issue occurs some time after having run the application through a few successful cycles.

Why does this happen and how can it be fixed?

Code:

```
package test3d;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

class ColoredTriangle {
    public void start() {
        try {
            Display.setFullscreen(true);
            DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(34,34);
           // Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(DisplayMode.get));
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

         // Init OpenGL
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GL11.glOrtho(-3, 3, -2.4, 2.4, -1, 1);
        GL11.glRotatef(0.0f,5.0f,1.0f,0.0f); 
        //GL11.glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 1, -1);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

        boolean quit = false;

        while (!quit) {         
            // Clear the screen.
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            //GL11.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CCW);
            // Begin drawing
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            GL11.glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f); //Red   

     /*
                GL11.glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f, 0.0f);

                GL11.glVertex3f(0.0f,1.0f, 0.0f);

                GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f,1.0f, 0.0f);

                GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f); //*/


                 GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f, -1f);

                GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f,1.0f, -1f);

                GL11.glVertex3f(2.0f,1.0f, -1f);

                GL11.glVertex3f(2.0f,0.0f, -1f);

              GL11.glEnd();  



            Display.update();

            if (Display.isCloseRequested() || Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE))
                quit = true;
        }

        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
class Test3d
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ColoredTriangle ct = new ColoredTriangle();
        ct.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Run the program in the debugger. It should show you exactly what line the out of memory exception is occurring.

Comment: is the question:  why is netbeans stopping on the low memory condition?  (there is a setting for that).  Or is the question:  why is there a menory leak?  (that is a much trickier question.)

Comment: @JoshDM Program runs for few times well. Everytime i change the code i run the code to see it is working or not and everytime i press 'esc' to close the window. After repeating the same procedure some time memory exception is occuring

Comment: @StephanvandenHeuvel let me check it

Comment: @dingfelder I want to know why there is memory leak

Comment: @fallenAngel - I've posted an answer below which explains why there is a memory leak, with some workaround suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [known problem](http://netbeans.org/projects/platform/lists/dev/archive/2001-10/message/101) with NetBeans.

NetBeans JVM is not unloading the LWJGL DLL after each recycle, which is called via JNI through LWJGL on each execution of your application.

I know of a similar issue ([see this SO question referencing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228372/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-tomcat-from-crashing-when-a-loaded-jni-library-corrupt)) with the Tomcat Application Server running a web application which uses JNI.  If you unload and reload said JNI-accessing web application using the Tomcat administrator, the DLLs referenced by JNI are not unloaded and all sorts of problems and conflicts are encountered when the application is started back up.  The proper usage in said case is to completely stop the Tomcat service, then start Tomcat again.  It creates headaches for those who want to use the admin to update their JNI-referencing deployables; they have to do it manually.

Based on your evidence and [the first link](http://netbeans.org/projects/platform/lists/dev/archive/2001-10/message/101), NetBeans also suffers from this issue and the only workarounds are to either:

1. not reload your application so often
2. restart the IDE after a couple of application reloads
3. use a different IDE that might not do this (perhaps [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org)?)

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar memory problem on my Linux Debian.

Here is how to fix it:

1. run a terminal
2. log in as root
3. type `crontab -e`
4. scroll to the bottom or the file and type `* * * * * sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

This magic line cleared all unused ram every minute.  It removed the unused memory NetBeans was producing (including any other memory-consuming programs).

This should work on most UNIX like OS's.